# Is it possible to copy Scratch 2 from Pi to PC?

Tags: scratch

I am running a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

I have Scratch 2 installed and would like to copy the program over to my laptop so I work with Scratch offline. I have the SD card and the Micro SD card to transfer from the Pi to the laptop, is it possible to transfer the Scratch program over using this method?

I know that there is an option to [download](https://scratch.mit.edu/download) Scratch but I was wondering if it could be copied across without the nead to download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the Scratch 2.0 Offline Editor on the website i assume that's what you want.
https://scratch.mit.edu/download

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way of copying that across so I don't have to download it or is that not possible?

Comment: Thats not possible unless you laptop is linux but I'm still not sure if you could do it.

Comment: no its not Linux, I assume that the Scratch on Pi is Linux then and doesn't work with windows 10. Thanks for the help, I'll download it directly from Scratch

Comment: For posterity, I don't think it could be transferred across to the PC even if it were using Linux.  At a glance, I think scratch is implemented using a form of smalltalk, which itself is implemented in C, meaning the machine code binaries are [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) specific.  Contemporary PC's pretty much as a rule use x86(-64) processors whereas the Pis, like most contemporary mobile and embedded devices, use ARM based processors.